# проблемы с синхронизацией проекта с gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

Помогите пожалуйста не могу синхронизировать проект с gradle пишет bad_certificates хотя у меня в настройках сертификации с сервером принимаются автоматически недоверенные сертификаты. В поиске нет решения подобной проблемы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что за синхронизация, какие сертификаты  ?

Comment: File - Sync project with gradle files дает подобную ошибку.

Comment: первый раз такое вижу.. проверьте параметры в org.gradle.jvmargs, там какие-то пробелы, русские буквы

Comment: Дело в том, что эту строку я добавил уже после имеющейся ошибки(((

Comment: недостаточно информации